# What is a co-dimension?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I'm looking for a simple explanation (without complex formula) what a co-dimension is. When does objects have a co-dimension of 0 and when > 0?

Context: [A Critical Comparison of the 4-Intersection and 9-Intersection Models for Spatial Relations: Formal Analysis](http://www.spatial.maine.edu/~max/4Vs9.pdf) (see abstract)

Comment: codimension is usually used in the context of vector spaces : The codimension of a subspace $W\subset V$ is the dimension of $V/W$

Comment: If an object $W$ has codimension of zero (relative to an object $V$), that means that $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$. Otherwise, $\dim(W)< \dim(V)$.

Comment: codimension is also used in the context of manifolds. If $N$ is a submanifold of $M$, then $\dim M - \dim N$ is the codimension of $N$.

Comment: As you can see, the word "codimension" is used in many contexts in somewhat different (though related) ways, so to clarify your question you should give some more context.

Comment: I did add a link to the PDF mentioning co-dimension. However, I guess the comment of @TylerClark pretty much describes the usage of co-dimension. I haven't realized that this word was used in different contexts before. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a subobject $A$ of $X$ such that both $A$ and $X$ have finite dimension, the *codimension*, which is short for *complementary dimension*, of $A$ relative to $X$ is $\dim X - \dim A$.

Comment: This doesn't work if one speaks of a subspace of finite codimension in an infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I edited my answer to take in account your correction.

Answer (score 1):

The codimension of a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ is the dimension of the space of cosets of $W$ in $V$.  A coset is a set of the form $v+W=\{v+w : w\in W\}$.  One can add two cosets or multiply a coset by a scalar, so the set of cosets is a vector space in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

The term arises when you are considering some type of mathematical object for which dimension makes sense, and you have a subobject of a larger object. For example:

- A subspace $U$ of a (finite dimensional) vector space $V$.
- A submanifold $N$ of a manifold $M$.

The codimension of the small object is the dimension of the larger object minus that of the small object. So in the examples, $\operatorname{codim}{U}=\dim{V}-\dim{U}$ (which is equal to $\dim{V/U}$ as mentioned in the comment - and this extends the definition to allow $V$ to be infinite dimensional), and $\operatorname{codim}{N}=\dim{M}-\dim{N}$.

Note that the codimension of the small object is not intrinsic, but depends on the choice of large object; if you have vector spaces $U,V,W$ with $U$ a subspace of $V$ and $V$ a subspace of $W$, then the codimension of $U$ in $V$ is different from the codimension of $U$ in $W$ (providing $V\ne W$!).

The case that a subobject has codimension $0$ is special, as this is the case where its dimension is as large as possible, given that it is a subobject of the larger object. So $U$ has codimension $0$ in $V$ only when $U=V$, and $N$ has codimension $0$ in $M$ only when $N$ contains an open subset of $M$.